# C++, issue with using getline and cin.ignore() in for loop.Getline is skipping by second iterate in the for loop

Tags: c++

I have been trying to figure out why it doesn't read my second getline(). The first getline(cin, line) works fine. No errors or anything. it just skips that line by the second iterate in the loop. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    int main() {
    
        int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector <int> arrNumbers;
        int requestLine = 0;
        std::string line;
        double procent = 0;
    
        if (n > 99) {
            std::cout << "wrong range of number" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int num;
            std::cin >> num;
            arrNumbers.push_back(num);
        }
    
        std::cin >> requestLine;
        for (int i = 0; i < requestLine; i++) {
    
            std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
            std::getline(std::cin, line);
                    
            
            int del1 = line.find_first_of(' ', 0);  // first position of space
            int del2 = line.find_first_of(' ', del1 + 1); // second position of space
    
            std::stringstream indexStr(line.substr(0, del1)); // position
            std::stringstream numberStr(line.substr(del1, del2)); // number
            std::stringstream repeatsStr(line.substr(del2)); // repied
    
            int index, number, repeats;
    
            indexStr >> index; 
            numberStr >> number; 
            repeatsStr >> repeats;
    
            arrNumbers.insert(arrNumbers.begin() + index - 1, repeats, number);
    
            del1 = 0;
            del2 = 0;
            
            
        }
    
        for (const int& number: arrNumbers) {
            sort(arrNumbers.begin(), arrNumbers.end());
        }
    
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `std::cin.ignore()` line out of the loop and just below your last `std::cin`? I also think your knowledge of `std::stringstream` might need some tweaking. One stringstream will feed all three variables just fine.

Comment: `std::cin.ignore(256, '\n')` call ignores all characters up to and including end-of-line. On the first iteration of the loop, it eats EOL left over after `std::cin >> requestLine`. On the second iteration of the loop, it eats the whole second line of input.

Comment: @sweenish thank you,you solved my problem and i am agree about the stringstream.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that the program came inside the loop?
Check the value of “n” just before it.

Comment: thank you for your help, the issue was because of the cin.ignore().